# TokenMismatchException : even if there's a _token passed [LARAVEL]

Tags: laravel-5, csrf

Had u encounter the same issue. We've got a:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
```

though in our forms we have this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}} />

{!!Form::hidden('token',crsf_token())!!}

{!!csrf_field()!!}
```

or whatever you think on how to include the csrf_token, we did that already. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have anything listed in `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware?

Comment: nope. we didn't modify any on the Http/Middleware

Comment: It seems like the session is not working.

Comment: Does your Kernel have the StartSession middleware? Also, what session driver are you using?

Comment: Are you by any change destroying the session or cookies in the same request, which could be deleting the CSRF token in the cookie? The other issue could be that some JavaScript is overwriting the value of `_token` field on submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by enabling ARR Afinity and Php version.